# Compute sum of digits of a given string in python

Tags: python, sum, digits

I have this string and I want to calculate the sum, but it doesn't show the right answer, it prints 51.

```py
sumAndAverage = "English = 78 Science = 83 Math = 68 History = 65"

def sum_digits_string(str1):
    sum_digit = 0
    for x in str1:
        if x.isdigit():
            z = int(x)
            sum_digit = sum_digit + z

    return sum_digit 

print(sum_digits_string(sumAndAverage))
```

Comment: it calculates the sum of all the digits (7+8+8+3+6+8+6+5). do you want to calculate the sum of all numbers?

Comment: well, 7+8+8+3+6+8+6+5 = 51 :-) sum of digits. what you expect?

Comment: Your program sums the individual digits not "whole" number

Comment: that's because it reads each digit and adds it, you have 7+8+8+3+6+8+6+5

Answer (score 1):

The best (Pythonic) way to do it using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). Try this:

```
sumAndAverage = "English = 78 Science = 83 Math = 68 History = 65"

li = [int(x) for x in sumAndAverage if x.isdigit()]
print("List:", li, "=", sum(li))
```

Output:

```
List: [7, 8, 8, 3, 6, 8, 6, 5] = 51
```

If you want to calculate the sum of numbers in your string:

```
sumAndAverage = "English = 78 Science = 83 Math = 68 History = 65"

li = [int(x) for x in sumAndAverage.split() if x.isdigit()]
print("List:", li, "=", sum(li))
```

Output:

```
List: [78, 83, 68, 65] = 294
```

Comment: OP code does the same. Obviously their problem statement is not correct

Answer (score 1):

Try using `re`:

```
sumAndAverage = "English = 78 Science = 83 Math = 68 History = 65"
nums = re.findall('\d+', sumAndAverage)
nums = [int(num) for num in nums]
print(sum(nums))
# 294
```

Regex will try and find all numbers in your string, store them to a `list`, then you just need to sum them up.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a possible solution. Now you have as a result 229 (78 + 83 + 65).

The problem with your code was that you were summing all the numbers in the string, but you did not consider that number may be more than one character in length.

```py
sumAndAverage = "English = 78 Science = 83 Math = 68 History = 65"

def sum_digits_string(str1):
    sum_digit = 0
    num = ""
    for x in str1:
        if x.isdigit():
            num += x
        else:
            if num != "":
                z = int(num)
                sum_digit += z
                num = ""
    return sum_digit 

print(sum_digits_string(sumAndAverage))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're casting each digit separately, so what you're doing is 7 + 8 + 8 + 3 + 6 + 8 + 6 + 5 which is indeed 51. What you want to do here is splitting your string and casting the entire numbers, try something like this :

```
sumAndAverage = "English = 78 Science = 83 Math = 68 History = 65"

def sum_digits_string(str1):
    sum_digit = 0

    for x in str1.split(" "):
        if x.isdigit():
            z = int(x)
            sum_digit = sum_digit + z

    return sum_digit 

print(sum_digits_string(sumAndAverage))
```

That is working an giving 294.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'English = 78 Science = 83 Math = 68 History = 65'    
a = sum([int(s) for s in str.split() if s.isdigit()])
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is printing sum of individual digits and not numbers. In your case, you can use `split()` method to achieve what you intend to do:

```
sumAndAverage = "English = 78 Science = 83 Math = 68 History = 65"

def sum_digits_string(str1):
    sum_digit = 0

    for x in str1.split():
        if x.isdigit():
            sum_digit += int(x)

    return sum_digit

print(sum_digits_string(sumAndAverage))
```

**Output:** 294

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with a single line of code

```
sumAndAverage = "English = 78 Science = 83 Math = 68 History = 65"
```

**Solution 1:**

```
from functools import reduce

>>> reduce(lambda a, x: int(a)+int(x), [int(s) for s in sumAndAverage.split() if s.isdigit()])
294
```

**Solution 2:**

```
>>> sum([int(s) for s in sumAndAverage.split() if s.isdigit()])
294
```